# Android: Getting a user library onto an AVD in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am trying to get a library (eg. uses-library) onto an AVD, if I push it with ADB the OS doesn't know it exists, and restarting the emulator clears the pushed file from memory. I found that it is possible to load a library when starting the emulator:

> If your application declares a
> uses-library element in its manifest
> file, the application can only run on
> a system image in which that external
> library is present. If you want to run
> your application on an emulator,
> create an AVD that includes the
> required library. Usually, you must
> create such an AVD using an Add-on
> component for the AVD's platform (for
> example, the Google APIs Add-on
> contains the Google Maps library).
>
> http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/index.html

How do I include my library from file, not from add-on?

Comment: Are you not able to just include the jar in the build path?

Comment: Where does the library come from? Is it your own library, or are you expecting it to come pre-installed on some particular device?

Answer (score 0):

If the library is in a APK then you need to copy it to the devices and then install it using the package manager on the emulator.

If the library is in a Jar then you need to add it to your projects build path. After you do this the library will be included into the compiled APK and will be puto on the emulator when you install your APK.